# Incorrect Model.ID being passed to Delete Action from View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller

I am using a single MVC action controller called "Edit" to allow me to Edit, Create or Copy records.  However, the View model for this action doesn't submit Model IDs consistently when I try to delete records. Here is the button that calls the delete action.

```
<input class="btn btn-info btn-danger" asp-controller="Bags" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" onclick="alert(@Model.Id);" type="submit" value="Yes" />
```

That line of code lets me delete an Edited or Created record, but when I try to delete a newly Copied record, the ID that's passed to the Delete action is the ID of the original record, not the copied record.

Here is the code for the Edit Action that creates/edits/copies records and calls the View.

```cs
// GET: Bags/Edit/5
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, bool? copy)
{
    Bagsmvc bag = new Bagsmvc();
    ViewBag.Copy = false;

    // When id is not null, we are editing or copying.  Otherwise, we're creating 
    // EDIT a bag
    if(id != null)
    {
        bag = await _db.Bags.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    } else
    // CREATE a new blank bag
    {
        await _db.Bags.AddAsync(bag);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); ;
    }

    // COPY a bag
    // This is a real hack.  Once the button is hit, the bag is copied and saved to the db.  Setting Id = 0 somehow
    // indicates to the Entity Framework to add the record in with a newly generated ID.  
    // Also, since we don't want an exact copy, bring user to edit screen to make the changes.
    if (copy != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Copy = true;
        bag.Id = 0;
        await _db.Bags.AddAsync(bag);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); ;
    }

    return View(bag);
}
```

Now here are some screen shots where you can see that the bag number is correct in the view. But when I submit "Yes" the debugger confirms that the old ID number is passed to the delete action.
[image: Initiate the copy]

I click on "Copy Bag" for old record #3079.  The code creates new item #3088, which I am going to delete.

[image: Newly created record #3088]

I confirm deletion and somehow the Delete action thinks I'm deleting the original record (id = 3079 in debugger) not the copy 3088 (which is what @Model.Id should be bound to)

[image: Debugger shows ID as 3079 (the record copied from)]

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured out how to fix it, but I still don't know why it was a problem.  The issue was created by code I didn't post.  Earlier in the View model code, the form with the Delete button has these lines:

```
<h1>ID: @Model.Id</h1>
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
```

For some reason, the h1 @Model.Id is set to 3088, but the hidden button somehow remains bound to 3079.  Why would it do this?  What am I missing?

As a workaround, I eliminated the hidden field for my Copy operation so that the asp-route-id is used instead

```
<h1>ID: @Model.Id</h1>
@if (ViewBag.Copy == false)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Id" />
    }

...

<input class="btn btn-info btn-danger" asp-controller="Bags" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" type="submit" value="Yes" />
```

If anyone has insight to this, I'd love to know why the Model is binding incorrectly in the hidden field.  Is there some weird persistence that's happening that I don't know about?